# ResponsiveSlides How do I make the width of the images occupy entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-slides

I want make that the width of images ocuppy entire page just like this:

http://i1240.photobucket.com/albums/gg491/Nerio_Navea/Screenshots/GoogleChrome2014-12-30220149_zps99e94bc2.png

but I can't find a property for this.

I'm new using Jquery but I understand Javascript

Please someone helpme with this

i'm new on StackOverflow

Sorry for my english ;D

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Can you put your code on codepen.io or jsfiddle? it'll be easier for people to help you, that way.

Comment: http://codepen.io/nerionavea/details/dPNbYP/

Comment: i'm using ResponisveSlides with is a Jquery Plugin that create a image slider but it's default width size don't occupy the entire page size, i wan't make that this slider width size occupy the 100% of the explorer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want, but you can insert the image in a `div`, or use `float` so that your image can come out of the normal margins.

Here is what you can try (using in-line CSS):

```
<image src = " " style = "position: absolute; left:10; top: 100;">
```

Just specify the exact place where you want to place the image by writing the left and top co-ordinates in their respective places. This is what I got after reading your question.

And, this way you can make your image occupy even the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to craft a Responsive Slideshow this might be of some help. This is an example using Javascript/HTML to include a slideshow with your slider.

1. Javascript Code

```js
<!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //Define an array of slideshow transition code
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        { code1 },
        { code2 },
        { code3 }
        ];
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $SlideshowOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                    $ShowLink: true
                }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>
```

2. HTML Code

```html
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```